# How to extract Complete data from database

Tags: database

Just like a database of website http://result.biselahore.com/ it allows us to enter roll number to get our result. Is there any way to get the whole data.
I want to create a PDF file of the whole data in their database.

Comment: If you don't have the database access the you can't implement or generate report  programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a contact address and ask them for a copy of their data. You will probably have to explain why you need it. They may say no, in which case you ***absolutely should not*** try to reconstruct it by flooding the form with automatically-generated roll numbers and scraping the results. Seriously: don't do that.